# Air Native Extension Build Error ios

Tags: ios, xcode, apache-flex, air, air-native-extension

I am trying to make native extension in AIR for nativeCamera Extension in iOS app. Which open camera from iOS when i click on button from flex. When i make ane for it and include in my flex code and when i make build for iPA, At that time i show following error. i stuck from last 2 days but didn't get any solution. it's make me headache for finding solution.

[image: Error which generate when i build my flex Application]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are packaging against an iOS SDK. I'm not sure if they've added this option in Flash Builder on Windows as yet so you might have to use the command line:

```
adt -package
    -target ipa-test
    -provisioning-profile /path_to_provisioning_profile/Provisioning_Profile.mobileprovision
    -storetype pkcs12
    -keystore /path_to_certificate/certificate.p12
    -storepass xxxxx
    myApp.ipa
    application_xml_file.xml
    application_swf.swf
    -platformsdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
```

More information here: http://distriqt.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/252920-ld-framework-not-found